# How to access service annotaions of jax-rs deployed on jetty

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

I successfully created a web app with post services and its deployed on jetty

.

```
@Path("caas")
public class Cribservice {
  @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    //@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    //@Produces("text/xml")   // sends JSON
    public void setJson(String p) {
        String x = p;
        System.out.println(x);
        run(x);
    }
```

When i run this one using netbeans i can use all the services but after i successfully deployed this to jetty , i cant access the services .

> which address should I use to access resource location

:

> localhost:8080/caas/post
>
> localhost:8080/caas/Cribservice/webresources/caas/post
>
> Note : caas - context specified in jetty
>
> ```
>    Cribservice - class containing the jax-rs service implementation
>
>    caas(2) - @PATH
> ```

and this is how my Applicationconfig.java looks like :

```
package org.netbeans.rest.application.config;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestResourceClasses();
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify this method. It is automatically generated by NetBeans REST support.
     */
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestResourceClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(cribservice.Cribservice.class);
        return resources;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
localhost:8080/<NameOfYourProject>/caas/post
```

Given that configured jetty to run on 8080

Comment: i specified "caas" in context.xml under /etc/jetty/context, so when i visit http:/localhost:8080/caas I can see helloworld ,

caas is also given as @path("caas") and under class I have @path("/post")

Comment: i dont have xml servlet mappings in this case . I am using service as patterns to create services , insted of using maven

Comment: i edited my applicationconfig.java , is there anything wrong in it, i am not using web.xml but i assume netbeans will automatically configure appconfig.java in generated war file , is this assumption not making this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure Jersey is setup correct (assuming this is what you use). In web.xml, you need to add:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>`full_package_of_your_service`</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>`/service_path/*`</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will instruct Jersey where to find services and how the Jersey servlet path should look like.

Then you service will be available under: `http://localhost:8080/<YouAppName>/<service_path>/caas/post`

Mind that your service needs to be in the package (this is what Jersey expects): `full_package_of_your_service`

Comment: I am not using web.xml , i am using ApplicationConfig.java

Comment: i am using netbeans so even when i attempt to edit Applicationconfig.java it says donot modify this method it will be automatically generated by netbeans

Comment: by service_path do you mean application path specified in Applicationconfig.java

Comment: and what is 'full_package-of_your_service'

Comment: "full-package_of_your_service" is the Java package of your CribService class. Now looking over your initial URL for your service: http://localhost:8080/caas/Cribservice/webresources/caas/post, you should remove Cribservice and access it as http://localhost:8080/caas/webresources/caas/post. The pattern for the url is: <server>/<context>/<applicationpath>/<servicepath>/<servicemethodpath>